# Converting Grammar to a regular expression

Tags: regex, computer-science, grammar

From this grammar set I would like to construct a regular expression from it:

```
S -> bbD
D -> dD | dCbb
C -> cccC | cccE
E -> Eb | b
```

What I believe the regular expression should be:

```
(bb)(d+)(ccc+)(bbb+)
```

If this isnt correct, can someone point me in the right direction so I learn how to do it! Cheers.

Comment: please post code and not links to images

Comment: removed the images and added the code

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong on the `(ccc+)` part. `c` must always occur in triples (either from `cccC` or `cccE`) but `(ccc+)` also allows `cccc` The rest seems correct on the first glimpse. Technically, the last part should be `(b+bb)` but that's of course equivalent to `(bbb+)`